# Failed to connect to remote VM in Ubuntu

Tags: android

I am using Eclipse on Ubuntu to run and debug applications. When I want to run an application, the emulator works very well, but when I want to debug my application, it gives me this message:

> Launch error: Failed to connect to remote VM

I tried `adb kill-server` and `adb restart-server` and also restarting Eclipse, but with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem.
I had set a proxy on my Ubuntu in the system settings.
The avd could not access to emulator on port 8600.